# Javascript arrays y calculos

Tags: javascript, html5, array

Estoy intentando crear un `array` de `Strings` y darle un valor a cada uno de los elementos. Después calcular la longitud de cada `String` y multiplicar cada uno de ellos por la multiplicación anterior. Pero no funciona.

```
<h2> DEMO </h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var s,x=1;
var txt="";
String [] d = {"1X", "1", "X2", "1X2", "1", "1X", "X2", "1", "1X2", "1", "2", "1X", "X2", "2"};
Int [] e = [14];

for (s=0;s<=13;s++){
    e[s]=(d[s].length);
    x=x*e[s];
    txt = s + " " + d[s] + " " + x + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt; 
</script>
```

Comment: eso que has escrito es java o javascript?

Comment: Es javascript !

Comment: Los arrays en javascript se declaran con la siguiente sintaxis: `var nombreArray = ["valor1", "valor2", "valor3"];`

Comment: en javascript no existe la declaración String ni tampoco Int

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es multiplicar el largo entonces puedes usar esto.

```js
var d = ["1X", "1", "X2", "1X2", "1", "1X", "X2", "1", "1X2", "1", "2", "1X", "X2", "2"];
var result = 1;
d.forEach(function(e) {
  result *= e.length
});
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.length > 0 ? result : 0;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias. Muy útil. Aunque con el mismo array.for (s=0;s<=13;s++){e[s] = d[s].length; x *= e[s]; document.write(s + "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp" + e[s] + "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp" + x + "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp" + d[s] + "<br>");  Consigo cálculos parciales.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que así lo solucionaras por haber varias cosas en el código que creo que son las que estaban mal...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var s=0;
var x=1;
var txt="";
var d = {"1X", "1", "X2", "1X2", "1", "1X", "X2", "1", "1X2", "1", "2", "1X", "X2", "2"};
var e = [14];

for (s=0;s<=13;s++){
    e[s]=d[s].length;
    y=e[s]; 
    x=x*y;
    txt = txt + s + " " + d[s] + " " + x + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt; 
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias aunque creo que el array "d" debe ir entre [ ] en vez de entre { } y por eso al ejecutarlo da error. Veo que sin tener que utilizar la variable "y" y utilizando document.write en vez de document.getElementByID, consigo datos parciales, así como finales.